# Pixelation via SFML (2x,4x)

Tags: c++, sfml, pixelate

Is there any legal way to get this:
[True Pixels dot JPEG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQbda.png)

from this:
[Not_True Pixels dot JPEG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ICf2.png)

I got first one by real-time image filtering, but it provides random pixel selection and low amount of FPS.

```
    short   k = 4;
    sprite.setScale(k, k);
    ...
    rtexture.draw(sprite);
    ...
    image = rtexture.getTexture().copyToImage();
    for (int i = 0; i < image.getSize().x; i += k)
        for (int j = 0; j < image.getSize().y; j += k)
            for (int l = 0; l < k; l++)
                for (int m = 0; m < k; m++)
                    image.setPixel(i + m, j + l, image.getPixel(i, j));
```

P.S. I would like to scale whole window (or view) and get large pixels (2x, 4x), so any solutions may be good (such as WinAPI).